# Working with resources into maven shaded JAR

Tags: css, maven, javafx

I have next problem:

When I compile my project using maven, I receive shaded JAR with needed resources. But I use JavaFX and I need use this resources, and much resources... In my FXML files already set paths to css files for all needed interface elements, but JavaFX FXMLLoader can't load this files and FXML files because can't search it by them paths.

I already use this for loading FXML:

```
// Load FXML using InputStream. 
// Perfect works after many attempts with SlimeBot.class.getResource("/fxml/file.fxml") and other with getResource()
InputStream stream = SlimeBot.class.getResourceAsStream("/fxml/Main.fxml");
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
Parent root = loader.load(stream);
```

In one of my FXML:

```
// Loading stylesheets from FXML property
<TextField fx:id="locationField" alignment="CENTER" editable="false" layoutX="85.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="240.0" stylesheets="/css/dark/textfield/specificationTextField.css">
    <font>
        <Font size="12.0" />
    </font>
</TextField>
```

[Project resources structure (all resources correctly extract in JAR root)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbQXG.png)

But when I launch this program, I receive next exceptions:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2571)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at ru.soknight.slimebot.SlimeBot.start(SlimeBot.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$10(GtkApplication.java:245)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
    ... 11 more
```

How I can correctly load resources from JAR or how I can apply to all elements stylesheets from internal css files? Maybe I can use someone Maven plugin for it?

Comment: Fat/uber/shaded JARs don't change the layout of the application code/resources. The same resource path that works with a non-shaded JAR should work with a shaded JAR, assuming the shaded JAR was built correctly. Is that the _entire_ stack trace?

Comment: Yes. I can see also one stack trace with loading settings, but it is my problem. This should not affect the main problem.

Comment: Your code comments indicate you may have already done this, but try setting the location (i.e. using a `URL`) of the `FXMLLoader` rather than using an `InputStream`. For example: `new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Main.fxml"))`. Is there a reason you're using an `InputStream` in the first place?